# How to use Imputer in a DataFrameMapper on a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to use DataFrameMapper Imputer+Scaler mapping on all float64 columns of a dataframe. My code works with the StandardScaler but when I add the Imputer the mapper returns just one row with all zeros.

I saw this question 
[Imputer on some Dataframe columns in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38584184/imputer-on-some-dataframe-columns-in-python) and the tutorial https://github.com/paulgb/sklearn-pandas And there is a warning:

> site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py:386: DeprecationWarning:
>   Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17 and willraise
>   ValueError in 0.19. Reshape your data either using X.reshape(-1, 1) if
>   your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a
>   single sample.

So I understand that there is a shape mismatch. How should the below example dataframe be reshaped?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
from sklearn_pandas import DataFrameMapper
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, Imputer

# just a random dataframe from http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html
dates = pd.date_range('20130101', periods=6)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,4), index=dates, columns=list('ABCD'))

print "Starting with a random dataframe of 6 rows and 4 columns of floats:"
print df.shape
print df

mapping=[('A', [Imputer(), StandardScaler()]), ('C', [Imputer(), StandardScaler()])]
mapper = DataFrameMapper(mapping)

result = mapper.fit_transform(df)

print "I get an unexpected result of all zeroes in just one row."
print result.shape
print result

print "Expected is a dataframe of 2 columns and 6 rows of scaled floats."
print "something like this:"

mapping=[('A', [StandardScaler()]), ('C', [StandardScaler()])]
mapper = DataFrameMapper(mapping)

result_scaler = mapper.fit_transform(df)
print result_scaler.shape
print result_scaler
```

This the output

```
Starting with a random dataframe of 6 rows and 4 columns of floats.
(6, 4)
                   A         B         C         D
2013-01-01 -0.070551  0.039074  0.513491 -0.830585
2013-01-02 -0.313069 -1.028936  2.359338 -0.830518
2013-01-03 -1.264926 -0.830575  0.461515  0.427228
2013-01-04 -0.374400  0.619986  0.318128  0.361712
2013-01-05 -0.235587 -1.647786 -0.819940 -1.036435
2013-01-06  1.436073  0.312183  1.566990 -0.272224
Unexpected result is all zeroes in just one row.
(1L, 12L)
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
Expected is a dataframe of 2 columns and 6 rows of scaled floats.
something like this
(6L, 2L)
[[ 0.08306789 -0.21892275]
 [-0.21975387  1.61986719]
 [-1.40829622 -0.27069922]
 [-0.29633508 -0.4135387 ]
 [-0.12300572 -1.54725542]
 [ 1.964323    0.83054889]]
```

And a followup question - my original dataframe is a combination of floats, booleans and objects (labels). So when I have a list of

```
floats = list(df.select_dtypes(include=['float64']).columns)
mapping=[(f, [Imputer(missing_values=0,strategy="mean"), StandardScaler()]) for f in floats]
```

how could I prepare the dataframe (shape it for Imputer) just for those columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard Imputer doesn't work with the DataFrameMapper because the orientation of the input/output in the DataFrameMapper is the transpose of what is expected. Creating a wrapper class around Imputer should solve the problem:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer


class SeriesImputer(Imputer):
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return super(SeriesImputer, self).fit(X.reshape(-1, 1), y=y)

    def transform(self, X):
        return super(SeriesImputer, self).transform(X.reshape(-1, 1))
```

Then simply replace the occurrences of Imputer with SeriesImputer in the DataFrameMapper.

Answer (score 2):

As of now (version 1.1.0) there are much easier ways how to do this without necessity of creation additional wrapper class.

The first is a **specification of the column selector** which defines the shape of the array that is passed to the transformer:

- **simple string** (like `'A'`) - a one dimensional array will be passed
- **list with one element** (like `['A']`) - a two dimensional array with one column will be passed

So, in your case, it should be enough to change the mapping definition (note brackets around column names):

```py
mapping=[(['A'], [Imputer(), StandardScaler()]), (['C'], [Imputer(), StandardScaler()])]
mapper = DataFrameMapper(mapping)
```

Another option, in case you want to use the same transformation for all selected columns, is the use of `gen_features` function. You could do the following:

```py
from sklearn_pandas import DataFrameMapper, gen_features

feature_def = gen_features(columns=[['A'], ['C']], classes=[Imputer, StandardScaler])
mapper = DataFrameMapper(feature_def)
```

This answers also your second question. Just select your columns, use the right column selector type and combine it with `gen_features`.

```py
float_cols = list(df.select_dtypes(include=['float64']).columns)
# Use brackets for every column for 2D input shape
float_cols_2d = [[f] for f in float_cols]
```

The last "trick", if you prefer DataFrame output instead of numpy array, you can us `df_out=True` option for `DataFrameMapper`. The final example could look like following (note that I replaced `Imputer` with current `SimpleImputer`):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
from sklearn_pandas import DataFrameMapper, gen_features
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

dates = pd.date_range('20130101', periods=6)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,4), index=dates, columns=list('ABCD'))

float_cols = list(df.select_dtypes(include=['float64']).columns)
float_cols_2d = [[f] for f in float_cols]
feature_def = gen_features(columns=float_cols_2d, classes=[SimpleImputer, StandardScaler])
mapper = DataFrameMapper(feature_def, df_out=True)

result = mapper.fit_transform(df)
```

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. This is useful.

Comment: I'm wondering why could DataFrameMapper clamp feature names together, like post_year_post_month_0 post_year_post_month_1 instead of just post_year,post_month. Have you ever seen that? Code is DataFrameMapper(default=None, df_out=True, drop_cols=['title'],features=[(['post_year', 'post_month'],[SimpleImputer()])])

Comment: @AnatolyAlekseev I'm not sure what do you mean. In the example above, you want to pass two columns (`post_year` and `post_month`) to DataFrameMapper and then get them somehow combined? I do not understand it, sorry. Maybe it will be better if you try to open another question with a proper definition including examples what you expect and what you get.